Probablity of the product of 4 numbers

What is the probablity that any $4$ numbers arbitrarily selected from the set of natural numbers will have a product that ends with either $1$, $3$, $5$, or $7$.

As the product yields an odd number, I considered all end digit cases for the $4$ numbers which are odd and subtracted those cases which yield a nine.
For this I get:
$$5^4-62 $$
where the $62$ combination I have formed are:
$$(1,1,1,9);\ (1,9,9,9);\ (1,9,7,3);\ (1,1,7,7);\ (7,9,7,9);\ (9,3,9,3);\ (1,1,3,9),
$$
and their various arrangements.
Following this for the other digits we get an infinite GP with common ratio.
$$\frac{9^2}{10^2}$$
I wanted to verify if this is the correct way to approach such this question, and how else can I approach the problem.

$\frac{1}{2^5}\ - 62=-61.96875$ ; are you sure it is the probability that you want ?

What do you mean at the end of your message, when you search about other digits...

I've edited the message to improve readability (seen from my eyes). That $$62$$ that appears in the line with the probability makes no sense, and as it is typed I could not understand the intention (behind the forced white space introduced in mathjax by \  - which is not a "division by" sign). Please adjust...

Looks like $(1,1,3,9)$ should be replaced by $(1,1,3,3)$.

In addition to my earlier comment, you are missing two cases: $(3,3,3,7)$ and $(3,7,7,7)$

The wanted probability depends only on the last digit. Arguably, the probability space that models the situation is the space with $10^4$ elements:
$$
\Omega =\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}^4
$$
with all subsets measurable, and with the uniform probability $\Bbb P$ on it.
We consider now the event $E$ of all elements $(a,b,c,d)$ such that their product is among $1,3,5,7$. Elements of $E$ are called "good". It is better for our purposes to think of $\Omega$ as $(\Bbb Z/10)^4$, i.e. as the ring of integers modulo ten, taken in four copies of it. The invertible elements are then exactly $1,3,7,9$. The number $5$ is not invertible, but has the property that multiplied with any of $1,3,5,7,9$ is $5$ again.

We compute now the probability. Pick $(a,b,c,d)\in\Omega$.
If any of $a,b,c,d$ is among $0,2,4,6,8$, then $(a,b,c,d)\not\in E$. So we will restrict to $a,b,c,d$ among $1,3,5,7,9$, and call such elements "odd".

If none of $a,b,c,d$ is $5$, we have $a,b,c,d\in\{1,3,7,9\}$ invertible, and there are $4^4=256$ such cases. Then $abc$ is invertible in $\Bbb Z/10$. For fixed $a,b,c$ there is exactly one value $d\in\{1,3,7,9\}\subset \Bbb Z/10$ with $abcd=9$. The other three values for $d\in\{1,3,7,9\}$ lead to a "good" product in $\{1,3,7\}$. So there are $4^3\cdot 3$ "good" cases.
If at least one of $a,b,c,d$ is $5$, then $abcd=5$, so we have a "good" event $(a,b,c,d)$. We count $5^4$ cases with "odd" components, and eliminate the $4^4$ considered at the first subcase, which do not involve the $5$. (All remained tuples contain a five-component, so belongs to this second subcase.)

We count a total of $4^3\cdot 3+(5^4-4^4)=5^4-4^3=561$ "good" cases. So the wanted probability is:
$$
\Bbb P(E)=\frac{561}{10000}=0.0561\ .
$$

Computer check, here sage:
R = Integers(10)    # this is the ring ZZ modulo ten
p = sum([1 
         for a, b, c, d in cartesian_product([R, R, R, R])
         if  a*b*c*d in [1, 3, 5, 7]]) / 10^4
print(f"p = {p} = {p.n()}")

This gives:
p = 561/10000 = 0.0561000000000000

